# How to change the row color based value of Cell in list view

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to update the row color based on the value in one column, i have already applied the ItemContainerStyle to list view.

Code

```
<ListView KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3" x:Name="xListView"
          SelectionMode="Extended" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      DataContext="{Binding Path=FilteredItems}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          GridViewColumnHeader.Click="ListViewHeader_Click"
          Loaded="xListView_Loaded"
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}" 
          AlternationCount="2"
          MouseDoubleClick="xListView_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:RecoveryManager.ColHeader_Name}" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                        HeaderStringFormat="{}{0}      "/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:AccountManager.ColHeader_ID}" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}"
                        HeaderStringFormat="{}{0}      "/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:AccountManager.ColHeader_filename}"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=filename}" 
                        HeaderStringFormat="{}{0}      "/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:AccountManager.ColHeader_TransactStatus}"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TransactStatus}" 
                        HeaderStringFormat="{}{0}      ">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock x:Name="transType" Text="{Binding TransactStatus}"/>
               <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TransactStatus}"
                                       Value="pending">
                    <Setter TargetName="transType" Property="Background" 
                                      Value="#FF0000" />
                 </DataTrigger>
               </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Simply remove the `DisplayMemberBinding` from your `GridViewColumn` since you don't need to set it once you have already provided `CellTemplate` to your column.
You don't need to set both at same time.

Remove `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TransactStatus}"` and your trigger will work perfectly.